# No route matches [POST] when submitting new form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

I am getting a "No route matches [POST]" when submitting a new form.

```
### /routes.rb ###

resources :artists, controller: 'artists/artists', only: [:show] do
  member do
    resources :videos, controller: 'artists/videos', only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
  end
end

### /artists/videos/videos_controller.rb ###

class Artists::VideosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_artist

  def new
    @video = ArtistVideo.new
  end

  def create
    @video = @artist.create_artist_video(video_params)
    if @video.save
      redirect_to current_artist
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

   private
     def set_artist
       @artist = current_artist
     end
end

### /artists/videos/new.html.erb ###

<%= form_for(@video, url: new_video_path) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :video_title, "title", class: "label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :video_title, class: "text-field" %>

    <%= f.label :video_description, "decription", class: "label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :video_description, class: "text-field" %>

    <%= f.label :youtube_video_url, "youtube url", class: "label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :youtube_video_url, class: "text-field" %>

    <%= f.submit "add video", class: "submit-button" %>
<% end %>

### rake routes ###

videos_path         GET      /artists/:id/videos(.:format)          artists/videos#index
                    POST     /artists/:id/videos(.:format)           artists/videos#create
new_video_path      GET      /artists/:id/videos/new(.:format)       artists/videos#new
edit_video_path     GET      /artists/:id/videos/:id/edit(.:format)  artists/videos#edit
video_path          PATCH    /artists/:id/videos/:id(.:format)       artists/videos#update
                    PUT      /artists/:id/videos/:id(.:format)       artists/videos#update
```

So not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried taking :index completely out so videos_path uses the post method, but I still have the same problem.

I'm using the has_many method linking videos to artists, if that even matters.

Not sure if it's the routs or the controller code that's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifying a path `url: new_video_path` but that is for `videos#new` and what you *want* is the create path, which is a post to `videos_path(@artist)`. Since it's a nested resource, the path has to have the artist_id which it can get from the `@artist` instance.

But, the simpler way to do this is like so:

```
form_for[@artist, @video] do |f|
```